# HTC One X Video Sync problem

Tags: sync, video, htc-one-x

Here is a video of the problem I am having.

Basically, when I am recording a video and the phone receives a notification (even if the phone is on silent) the video and audio step out of sync massively!!

See the link below, I made a video to show what I mean.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9CYqAqPLS4